# Keyboard shortcut to select address bar in Total Commander

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, total-commander, norton-commander

What's the keyboard shortcut to focus/select the address bar in Total Commander (or Double Commander, Norton Commander e.g., any of its clones)?

[image]

In browsers it's usually <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
If it doesn't exist, can it be configured? The options only offer cm_FocusCmdLine (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), but no command to focus the address bar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What's the keyboard shortcut to focus/select the address bar in Total Commander?

> I cannot find an easy way to get my cursor into the directory/address bar to immediately start typing a network path or directory, I have to click once or twice to get it editable.

...

> Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> while focus is on [..] item.

...

> Or assign the command `cm_EditPath` to a shortcut, an alias, a button or a menu item.

Source [Keyboard shortcut to quickly type into Directory/address bar](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=16776&view=next)

Comment: cm_EditPath, that's what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Following the advice from https://chodounsky.net/2013/08/02/access-total-commander-path-with-shortcut, here's how you can set Ctrl+L to go to the address bar in Total Commander:

Configuration->Options->Misc->Redefine hotkeys, then set to Ctrl+L, choose the command to be cm_EditPath, and click the tick icon:

[image]