# Total Commander: Select bottom text box

Tags: total-commander

After upgrading to version 9 and also having created a custom column view. I can no longer select the bottom command / textbox with pressing the "right-arrow".

Right-arrow behaves as down-arrow button, selecting the next file.

Is there a way to get the old right-arrow behavior back or is there a shortcut for changing focus to the command-box.

Answer (score 0):

After having read this: [Keyboard shortcut to select address bar in Total Commander](https://superuser.com/questions/882822/keyboard-shortcut-to-select-address-bar-in-total-commander)

I tried creating a hotkey for "RIGHT" to cm_FocusCmdLine, and it works.

Comment: do you mean this as a comment / answer / or addition to your question? Please clarify and move the information to the appropriate place. If you wish to keep this as an answer, then please remove the question (you're fine to move it to your question), and elaborate a bit more the solution, link only answers are discouraged here at superuser.